# Servlets and Filters registered as Spring Beans instead of web.xml in Grails

Tags: spring, grails

In the Grails ['Upgrading from 2.x to 3.0.6' document](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/upgrading.html) it's been noted that "new servlets and filters can be registered as Spring beans or with ServletRegistrationBean and FilterRegistrationBean respectively" however not much else is said on the matter.

I am wondering if anybody has any good input on how to do this properly (i.e., using the init/BootStrap.groovy which contains the servlet context to load beans, versus beans in conf/spring) or perhaps there is some pre-defined Spring way of doing this that's obvious and I am missing.

Note: I am trying to integrate spring-ws into Grails 3.0.6.

Answer (score 6):

You should do this in `doWithSpring` for a plugin, or `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` for an app. Since Grails 3 is based on Spring Boot you can also use an `@Bean` method.

When the application context starts up, Spring looks for `ServletRegistrationBean`s, `FilterRegistrationBean`s, etc. and uses their configured properties to do programmatic registration in the servlet container for you.

There are some examples in the Grails source. ControllersGrailsPlugin registers some filters (e.g. [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.0.7/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/controllers/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L89)) and the main dispatcher servlet is registered [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.0.7/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/controllers/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L140).

There's some documentation in the [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) although it's biased towards `@Bean` methods, but you can use any approach to defining the beans.

Answer (score 2):

(Works for Grails 3 (specifically version 3.3.3))

To add custom **listener** to **servletContext** by using "**doWithSpring**" section of plugin descriptor file (*GrailsPlugin.groovy):

***Step #1***

***GrailsPlugin.groovy**

```
...
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean
import my.custom.listeners.ContextListener
...
class MyAppGrailsPlugin extends Plugin {
...
    Closure doWithSpring() {
        {->
        ...
        httpSessionServletListener(ServletListenerRegistrationBean){
            listener = bean(ContextListener)
        }
        ...
    }
...
}
```

***Step #2***: Now it can be referred in e.g. service classes as:

**SomeService.groovy**

```
class SomeService{        
    ...
    def httpSessionServletListener
    ...
    def someMethod(){
        httpSessionServletListener.getSessions()
    }
    ...
}
```

***Step #0***: Custom filter class should be written

Here is the snippet of custom listener class implementing respective interface:

**ContextListener.groovy**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener

public class ContextListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    ...
    /**
     * All current sessions.
     */
    public List<HttpSession> getSessions() {
        synchronized (this) {
            return new ArrayList<HttpSession>(sessions)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```