# How to use an existing web.xml in my new grails 3 app?

Tags: spring-boot, grails, grails3

According to the documentation [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.x/guide/upgrading.html#upgradingApps) it says:

> If you have a modified web.xml template then you will need to migrate this to Spring as Grails 3.x does not use a web.xml (although it is still possible to have on in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml).

which I interpret to mean that if I'm incorporating a 3rd party proprietary library that has a `web.xml`, then I can put it in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` unaltered (along with everything else that they put in their tomcat webapp directory) and grails will load it. Is this interpretation correct? That's what seems to be implied by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191269/319034) answer.

I started a grails 3 app with the `react` profile (I tried the `web` profile too) and a webpage with calls their servlet. However, while an html file in `webapp` can be found, the servlet call itself is returning `404` and I can't figure out why. If I build a war file and deploy on a standalone tomcat, the servlet call works, but when I run like this:

```
./gradlew server:bootRun --debug
```

then it doesn't, and I don't see anything interesting printed to the console.

Is there some URL mapping I need to manipulate or something in `application.yml`?

In the web.xml, the servlet that's being called looks like this (this is a small piece of it, does it am):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DataSourceLoader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.isomorphic.servlet.DataSourceLoader</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DataSourceLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/isomorphic/DataSourceLoader</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I realize the alternative is to rewrite `web.xml` using [Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564857/servlets-and-filters-registered-as-spring-beans-instead-of-web-xml-in-grails) and put stuff in `resources.groovy`, but I'd prefer an approach that requires as little of my coding as possible.

[update]

I've been able to update my `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` with this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    DataSourceLoader(ServletRegistrationBean) { bean ->
         servlet = new com.isomorphic.servlet.DataSourceLoader()
         urlMappings = ['/isomorphic/DataSourceLoader']
    }        
}
```

and it seems to be working... Nevertheless, I am still interested in ways to only use `web.xml`, if possible, which is my original question.

Answer (score 0):

As part of an upgrade from Grails 2.x to Grails 3.3,  I had been previously using web.xml to define 3rd party servlets.

The approach I took in order to make these servlets available(and load at startup) was through a custom class.  So you can define a custom class, in src/java as such:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ServletRegistrations {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean fileServlet(){        
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new FileServlet(), "/files/*");

        // to load add startup uncomment the line below
        //registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        // define init param
        registration.addInitParameter("basePath","/WEB-INF/resources");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

So although you don't define everything in one XML file, you can still define all your servlets in this one single class, so it's not a big change and I now I've gone through this once, I prefer to be able to do the definitions in code rather than xml. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the example, I think I'll do some testing today. Do you happen to have some documentation for how to convert a web.xml into `Bean`s?

It sounds like migrating away from web.xml might be a good move but I'd like to confirm that it's not some configuration/misconfiguration that's preventing my web.xml from working unaltered...

Comment: I believe it's the change within Grails to use Spring Boot that's the factor here.